# How to change sas plot x axis order

Tags: sas

I have a dataset like the following:

```
x          y
16:00      1
17:00      2
18:00      2
19:00      3
20:00      4
21:00      5
22:00      6
23:00      1
24:00      1
01:00      2
02:00      3
03:00      1
04:00      7
...
```

I want to plot the relationship between x and y using the following code. I want my x axis start from 16:00 and end at 04:00. However using the code below, x axis start from 00:00 and end at 16:00. can anyone teach me how to adjust my code please. ( i dont want to type the order one by one like the following order = ("16:00" ..."04:00").

```
PROC SGPLOT DATA = data;
SERIES X = x Y = y;
axis order=("16:00:00"t to "03:00:00"t by hour);
TITLE 'Plot';
RUN;
```

Comment: For SGPLOT the statement is XAXIS not AXIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that numerical X axis values cannot be put out of order.  And a time in SAS 1am < 11pm.  So you cannot go around the clock, so to say.

A work around is to make the time values date times.  That is, add a day component to it.  Then you only display the time portion.

```
data have;
informat x time5. y best.;
format x time5.;
input x y;
datalines;
16:00      1
17:00      2
18:00      2
19:00      3
20:00      4
21:00      5
22:00      6
23:00      1
24:00      1
01:00      2
02:00      3
03:00      1
04:00      7
;
run;

data have;
retain day 0;
set have;
format x_new datetime.;

/*Count Days*/
if x = "24:00"t then 
    day = day + 1;

x_new = dhms(day,hour(x),minute(x),second(x));
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
series x=x_new y=y;
xaxis valuesformat=tod5.;
run;
```

Here I am looking for the 24 hour mark to increment the day count.  Then creating a new variable to hold the day + the time.

When plotting, tell SAS to use the `TODw.d` format which only displays the time portion.

Here's what I get[image: produced graph]